# How to make a database updation, creation atomic, and roll back in case of incomplete updation?

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL. I want to perform these operations:

1. INSERT a record into a table.
2. CREATE a table if the above INSERT was successful.

How do I make sure that these two things happen as if they are a single DB statement. I mean, I do not want the INSERT to happen and then the CREATE to not happen due to any reason such as power cut, Internet connectivity issues etc.

And if CREATE is incomplete, I want the INSERT command to be rolled back.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're new to MySQL, you might start by learning the common usage patterns.  This is not one of them.  :)  Why do you want to do something wacky like this?

Comment: This is a bit weird in that creating tables (if they're not TEMP) should be pretty rare, but you could possibly do this using a transaction.  I'm not sure how well transactions would work with `CREATE` though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to package your INSERT and CREATE commands inside a transaction block that starts with START TRANSACTION and either ends with COMMIT if both commands succeed or ends with ROLLBACK if one of the command fails.